# Sitecore User Group July 2018 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are delighted to announce the July meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group.

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

- A futuristic showcase of the omni-channel capabilities of Sitecore XP by Rob Habraken - CTO & Sitecore MVP at Colours
- Sitecore and NightwatchJS: Our Experience Creating Integration Tests in Sitecore by Hugo Santos, Coveo For Sitecore Developer @Coveo

Join us for food, excellent company -- not to mention loads of terrible albeit obligatory puns -- and great cheer as we watch presentations on all things Sitecore!

**Date & Time (EST)**:- Wednesday, July, 11, 2018 6:00 PM

**Date & Time (UTC)**:- Wednesday, July, 11, 2018 10:00 PM

**Venue**:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here for more details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/251760886/).

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Jul 1 at 22:00 (UTC)